# How to add space between table cells in the body without affecting the header

Tags: html, css

I would like to customize the spacing between table cells. I know of the `border-spacing` property that can be added to the `table` tag. However, it is more global. It adds the spacing between header cells and body cells.

I want the space to be added to `tbody` cells only not the `thead`. Is that possible, how? And to take it further. Can it be customized in within the `tbody`? As in add the space between some columns while other columns don't get spacing? I also tried to `margin` but it doesn't work inside `table`
[image]

It would look like this where the to line is the bottom border for `thead` which doesn't contain any spacing. but the cells in the body do.
Padding won't work because it adds the space inside the border not between the cells

Comment: How would that look exactly? `border-spacing` is all you get and it's table-wide. There may be ways to fake the look you're going for but they have restrictions so are dependent on what specifically you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Use padding CSS Property `tbody td { padding: 12px }` If you want to apply this to the specific table then add the class or id attribute to the table. For example `<table class='example1'><tbody><tr><td>Col 1</td></tr></tbody></table>` then apply the css property like `.example1 tbody td {padding: 12px}`

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS definitions, specify something like this:

```
td {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

You can experiment with your settings in the tryout page on the **w3schools** page  **[here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_tbody_css).**

if you try tbody, you will see that it does not share the values with its "children".